# Laravel two wherehas queries not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to assign a group to users which have a role student and have also a particular selected group. There is a users table, which has pivot tables: role_user and group_user with roles and groups tables. Below is the code for the controller where I am trying to execute the query:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'add-group'      => 'required',
    'where-group'    => 'required'
]);

$selectedGroup = $request->input('add-group');
$whereGroupId  = $request->input('where-group');
$users         = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
                     $q->where('name', 'student');
                 })->whereHas('groups', function($q) {
                     $q->where('id', $whereGroupId);
                 })->get();

$selectedGroup = Group::whereId($selectedGroup)->first();
$users->assignGroup($selectedGroup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `orWhereHas` clause for the second half of the query.

Secondly, your `$whereGroupId` variable is not in the inner-function's scope, add a `use($whereGroupId)` statement to include it in the function's scope.

```php
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'student');
})->orWhereHas('groups', function($q) use ($whereGroupId) { // <-- Change this
    $q->where('id', $whereGroupId);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax error and a missing `use` to pass `whereGroupId`. I have no clue what `assignGroup` does, but this should fix the code you have.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'add-group' => 'required',
    'where-group' => 'required'
]);

$selectedGroup = $request->input('add-group');
$whereGroupId = $request->input('where-group');

$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->where('name', 'student');
    })
    ->whereHas('groups', function ($q) use ($whereGroupId) {
        $q->where('id', $whereGroupId);
    })->get();

$selectedGroup = Group::whereId($selectedGroup)->first();

$users->assignGroup($selectedGroup);
```

Comment: assignGroup is supposed to assign a group to a user. I got the solution above question however, another problem has comeup with assignGroup. I can only assign a group to only one user not to many as had intended. I will start another question on the same.

Comment: Solved the assignGroup problem by  using a foreach over each user and assigning them individually.